# php strip tags?

Tags: php, forms, math

I was just curious about this to see how this might work.

```
$number = "3/4";
echo $number;
```

and I get 3/4 as a string

```
$number = 3/4;
echo $number;
```

and I get 0.75 because it's doing the math

I am curious to see if there is a way to strip the "/" from the first one and have it divide number before the "/" by the number after the "/" so that it would come out as 0.75 instead of 3/4.

The reason I am building a form for a person who wants them to input the number in decimal form. However if a person inputs 3/4 I am going to kick an error that asks them to input it in decimal form and give them the decimal number.

Comment: with user interface things like that, i would try detect the / with js and give intimidate feedback as well as do the php validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `explode()` the expression using the "/" as the delimited then just do the math on the numbers.

```
<?php
    $number = "3/4";
    $num = explode("/", $number);
    $a = $num[0];
    $b = $num[1];

    $result = ((float)$a) / ((float)$b);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

A simple function would look like something below, you can throw more error handling in there if you want also.

```
function makeDecimal($string)
{
   $parts = explode('/',$string);
   if(count($parts) != 2)
    //throw error here
   return intval($parts[0]) / intval($parts[1]);
}
```